# Numerical solving of overdetermined, nonlinear equation system in Python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, numeric, nonlinear-optimization

Here's a minimal example of my problem - solved with scipy.optimize.leastsq

```
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
from numpy import array, exp, sin, cos

def MatrixFun(x, *par):
    a, b, c, d = par
    m11 = a*sin(x[0])+b*cos(x[1])
    m12 = c*cos(x[0])*sin(x[1])
    m21 = c*sin(x[0])/cos(x[1])
    m22 = d*exp(x[0]*x[1])
    M = array([[m11, m12], [m21, m22]])
    return M

def Residualvector(x, parameters):
    MatrixAim = MatrixFun([-1 , 1], *parameters)
    return (MatrixFun(x, *parameters)-MatrixAim).flatten()

parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4]
start = [0, 0]
print(leastsq(Residualvector, start, args=parameters))
```

> Problems:
>
> - Requires good starting point
> - Does not converge to desired values with my real systems
> - I need constraints for x

Here's my bruteforce solution for the example problem

```
from numpy import ones, array, arange, exp, sin, cos, sum, abs, argmin
from itertools import product as iterprod

def MatrixFun(x, *par):
    a, b, c, d = par
    m11 = a*sin(x[0])+b*cos(x[1])
    m12 = c*cos(x[0])*sin(x[1])
    m21 = c*sin(x[0])/cos(x[1])
    m22 = d*exp(x[0]*x[1])
    M = array([[m11, m12], [m21, m22]])
    return M  

def ResidualMatrix(x, parameters):
    MatrixAim = MatrixFun([-1 , 1], *parameters)
    return MatrixFun(x, *parameters)-MatrixAim

def MyBruteMatrixMinimizer(ResidualMatrix, ranges, args=()):
    pathongrid = list(iterprod(*ranges))
    pathlength = len(pathongrid)
    MatSum = ones(pathlength)
    for i in range(pathlength):
        MatSum[i] = sum(abs(ResidualMatrix(pathongrid[i], args)))
    pathgoal = pathongrid[argmin(MatSum)]
    return pathgoal

parameters = [1, 2, 3, 4]
ranges = [arange(-2,0,1e-2), arange(0,2,1e-2)]

print(MyBruteMatrixMinimizer(ResidualMatrix, ranges, args=parameters))
```

> Problems:
>
> - Slow
> - Stability unclear

I would rather be using scipy.optimize.brute or scipy.optimize.basinhopping which both lead to the error `TypeError: fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'F'`. This is clear as my matrix has more equations than variables (overdetermined).
The only idea I have so far is to sum up the absolut values of as many equations as necessary to reduce the output shape size - but I am absolutely not happy with that.
I would be very gratefull for alternate or improved solutions or any other advice.

Comment: This is not a working example and I don't really get what you want to achieve. By the way you may prefer to use `scipy.pi` instead of providing a value for pi in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use a least squares but rather use a good NLP (non-linear programming) solver. That would mean, for `F(x)=b` explicitly form:

```
min w'w
F(x) = b + w
```

Of course for any non-trivial NLP we want to pay attention to:

1. Provide good bounds (make sure all functions and gradients can be evaluated)
2. Provide a good initial point
3. Pay attention to scaling
4. Pay attention to singularities. E.g. you have a division which probably should be reformulated
5. If not using a modeling system with automatic differentiation, specify correct and exact gradients (and if needed 2nd derivatives). For complex
   models I would advice to use a modeling system that supports automatic differentiation and multiple nonlinear solvers (e.g. [GAMS](http://www.gams.com) or [AMPL](http://www.ampl.com)).